# Unit Test Fails at AuthenticationManager.Login(virtualUser)

Tags: unit-testing

We have a unit test for our Login method using Sitecore 8.2. It fails at the below piece of code and attached the error screenshot follows.

Can anybody please let me know how to resolve this error?

```
virtualUser.Profile.Save(); 
CacheManager.GetUserProfileCache().RemoveUser(virtualUser.Name); 
AuthenticationManager.Login(virtualUser);
```

---

[image]

Comment: Are you missing a BuildVirtualUser function with authentication = true?

Comment: @QuachNguyen it is present.